# Getting Run time Error 13: Type Mismatch (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, jira-rest-api

I am working on create JIRA API Request through Excel Macro. However I am getting an error of runtime error13: type mismatch for the line ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = j("issues")(i)("key") .
I have the authentication part, but unable to retrieve the results.

I tried changing the data types, but it is of no use.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call testAuthen

End Sub

Private Function UserPassBase64() As String
Dim objXML       As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim objNode      As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim arrData()    As Byte

arrData = StrConv("username:1234567", vbFromUnicode)

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData

UserPassBase64 = objNode.Text

End Function

Sub testAuthen()

 Dim JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 Dim Json$

 With JiraService
.Open "GET", "https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%20%3D%20ETM%20AND%20createdDate%20%3E%3D%20startOfMonth()%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Task", False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & UserPassBase64
.send
Json = .responseText

 Dim j As Object
 Set j = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Json)

 Dim i As Integer
 For i = 1 To 10
     ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = j("issues")(i)("key")
 Next i

 End With
 End Sub
```

Expected results is to display 5 JIRA columns (issue-key,summary,analyst,status,updated). However I am unable to proceed beyond authentication.
Since my queries are beyond 1000 issues,I want to write a code line which would create of loop of 50 results with each loop starting from the last issue of previous loop.

Comment: Did you look at the json response?  Is it what you expect?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I am not getting any json response. If I get any response, it is blank.